# How to keep using TimeMachine backups incrementally after disk upgrade?

Tags: time-machine, migration

I just upgraded disk on iMac: FusionDrive (small blade SSD + large HDD) -> dual larger SSDs working independently. Then I fully restored the system to the *boot*-SSD via Time Machine.

How can I keep backing up to TimeMachine incrementally reusing Fusion-time backups on both:

1. network-attached SMB drive
2. external HDD attached via USB directly to iMac?

---

Some specifics I need to consider:

- after I restored from (non-latest) backup on *network-attached* drive, a new backup to *local USB drive* was created as incremental--with no `associatedisk` / `inheritbackup` done yet
- conversely, a new backup attempted to *network-attached* drive sized as a from-the-scratch backup
- all Fusion-time backups *after* my restore point were consistently failing to restore, with a *"The backup disk was disconnected while restoring from the backup"* for network-attached drive, *"Error occurred while restoring from the backup"* for local USB drive
- I was never asked *"Would you like your Mac to inherit the backup history on the disk, or start a new backup?"* after the upgrade
- I successfully tested restoring from post-migration incremental backup made on the USB-attached drive

I'm still on Mojave 10.14.6; considering to upgrade to Ventura when I'm done with aftermath of the upgrade. I have 27" iMac Retina 5K, 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that no `associatedisk` / `inheritbackup` needed: Time Machine picked up the restored volume and is incremental immediately after the restore.

The reason it *looked like* non-incremental is that for network-attached drive, I forgot to exclude *secondary* SSD which contained a copy of original FusionDrive disk I made while testing restore from Time Machine.